# increase one item and update in one stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to Select one Item from Product table and then increase item, after that update Product table

```
USE [Buy100]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[IncVisited]
(
    @Product_Id bigint

)
AS

UPDATE [dbo].[Product] SET ([Visited_Item]+1) WHERE (([Product_Id]=@Product_Id))
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: As @Anand mentions, you should use `[Visited_Item] to reference itself. Why do you use all the brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update statement is wrong.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Product] SET [Visited_Item]=([Visited_Item]+1) WHERE (([Product_Id]=@Product_Id))
```